# C Preprocessor and enums – mistake in my code?

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

I have the following code in a global header, so I can make decisions at compile time:

```
enum {
    MyStyleA,
    MyStyleB,
    MyStyleC
};

#define STYLE MyStyleB
```

In various source files, I include this header and do something like this:

```
#if STYLE == MyStyleC
    doSomething();
#endif
```

Problem is, `doSomething()` definitely gets executed even though I defined `STYLE` to `MyStyleB` in the header!

Any idea what's going wrong here?

(I admit I am no **C** preprocessor expert.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the C preprocessor consider enum values as equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677148/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-consider-enum-values-as-equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a copy of the C standards on my bedside table, so I could be wrong, but:

The preprocessor has no idea what `MyStyleC` is - that doesn't get a value until it hits the compiler.

Compilers normally have an option (used to be -e ?) to output the results of the preprocessor phase (as text) - I'd look at that and see what your `#if` looks like after the preprocessor has gone over it.

Comment: Just tried that: the preprocessor directives are gone and the call to `doSomething()` is still present. :-)

Comment: `cc -E foo.c` typically sends preprocessor output to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor has no knowledge about the semantics of your code, it only does literal macro substitution so it can work with constant expressions only. How about writing

```
if (STYLE == MyStyleC) {
    doSomething();
}
```

instead?

Comment: Well, what if I want this decision to be made at compile time? And why don't I get a warning/error? What does the preprocessor think `MyStyleC` evaluates to?

Comment: @tajmahal "what if I want this decision to be made compile-time?" - then you are in the serious need of redesigning your code. "What does the preprocessor think MyStyleC evaluates to?" - That's something strange, since it doesn't know about the token it's processing, I'd also expect an error, but the thing is, you should not (ab)use the preprocessor like this. Instead of thinking about this quite pointless error, try reorganizing your code logic so that you don't need this ugly hack.

Comment: Well, I guess I could replace the enum with simple `#define`s to make it work …