# Why does the C preprocessor consider enum values as equal?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why does the `std::cout` line in the following code run even though `A` and `B` are different?

```
#include <iostream>

enum T { A = 1, B = 2 };
// #define A 1
// #define B 2

int main() {
#if (A == B)
    std::cout << A << B;
#endif
}
```

If I use `#define` instead (as commented out), I get no output as I expect.

Reason for the question:

I want to have a mode selector for some test code in which I can easily change modes by commenting/uncommenting lines on top:

```
enum T { MODE_RGB = 1, MODE_GREY = 2, MODE_CMYK = 3 };
// #define MODE MODE_RGB
#define MODE MODE_GREY
// #define MODE MODE_CMYK

int main() {
#if (MODE == MODE_RGB)
    // do RGB stuff
#elif (MODE == MODE_GREY)
    // do greyscale stuff
#else
    // do CMYK stuff
#endif

    // some common code

    some_function(arg1, arg2,
#if (MODE == MODE_RGB)
        // RGB calculation for arg3,
#elif (MODE == MODE_GREY)
        // greyscale calculation for arg3,
#else
        // CMYK calculation for arg3,
#endif
        arg4, arg5);
}
```

I know I can use numeric values e.g.

```
#define MODE 1 // RGB
...
#if (MODE == 1) // RGB
```

but it makes the code less readable.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: This is another one of those "the same name doesn't necessarily always refer to the same thing" things. If you uncomment the `#define`s and move them before the `enum` you'll get compilation errors.

Comment: Using `#define MODE_RGB 1` and `#define MODE MODE_RGB` seems elegant enough to me.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There are no macros called `A` or `B`, so on your `#if` line, `A` and `B` get replaced by `0`, so you actually have:

```
enum T { A = 1, B = 2 };

int main() {
#if (0 == 0)
    std::cout << A << B;
#endif
}
```

The preprocessor runs before the compiler knows anything about your `enum`. The preprocessor only knows about macros (`#define`).

Comment: "_The preprocessor only knows about macros (`#define`)_" is not totally correct; I'd rather say "_[...] only_ deals _with macros_".

Comment: To elaborate, you can define preprocessor macros with command line arguments (rather useful to be able to compile debug versions of a binary without changing any code). And of course, the compiler is free to allow other external methods to define preprocessor macros (without checking, I imagine IDEs would allow saving such data into a configuration file).

Answer (score 48):

This is because the preprocessor works before compile time.

As the enum definitions occur at compile time, A and B will both be defined as empty (pp-number `0`) - and thus equal - at pre-processing time, and thus the output statement is included in the compiled code.

When you use `#define` they are defined differently at pre-processing time and thus the statement evaluates to false.

In relation to your comment about what you want to do, you don't need to use pre-processor `#if` to do this. You can just use the standard `if` as both `MODE` and `MODE_GREY` (or `MODE_RGB` or `MODE_CMYK`) are all still defined:

```
#include <iostream>

enum T { MODE_RGB = 1, MODE_GREY = 2, MODE_CMYK = 3 };

#define MODE MODE_GREY

int main()
{
    if( MODE == MODE_GREY )
        std::cout << "Grey mode" << std::endl;
    else if( MODE == MODE_RGB )
        std::cout << "RGB mode" << std::endl;
    else if( MODE == MODE_CMYK )
        std::cout << "CMYK mode" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The other option using only the pre-processor is to do this as @TripeHound [correctly answered below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678859/3933895).

Comment: Why are they "defined as empty"? I had always thought "defined empty" means what you get if you simply `#define foo`, which results in it being replaced with blank space anywhere it appears in source code (resulting in, usually, a syntax error if you try to use it somewhere a value belongs).

Comment: @Random832 sorry my choice of "random" probably wasn't a great word here. Things that are `#define`d without an explicit definition are given the pp-number 0. (C99 Standard)

Comment: @Samidamaru: Thanks for your update. The reason I can't use a conventional if is that the preprocessor #if blocks contain further preprocessor commands e.g. #defines. I know it's a mess, but it just for a throwaway test program :-)

Comment: @Gnubie fair enough. Well, looks like you can either do this or the `#define` method which you commented on below (TripeHound's answer). I think they're the only realistic solutions :). Hope I helped anyway. Don't forget to accept the best answer you've gotten if they answered your question to help future users!

Comment: Since the snippet from TripeHound is on the same page as your answer, consider removing the copy-paste, and either just retain your sentence "The other option ... correctly answered below" or link to TripeHound's answer directly using the URL from the *share* link under that answer.

Comment: @Lawrence That's a much better idea. Thanks :).

Answer (score 26):

Identifiers that are not defined macros are interpreted as value 0 in conditional preprocessor directives. Therefore, since you hadn't defined macros `A` and `B`, they are both considered 0 and two 0 are equal to each other.

The reason why undefined (to the pre-processor) identifiers are considered 0 is because it allows using undefined macros in the conditional without using `#ifdef`.

Comment: Just upping this since you are the only one one actually points out that NON defined is treat as `0`. Didn't know so far

Answer (score 12):

As the other answers said, the C preprocessor doesn't see enums. It expects, and can only understand, macros.

Per [the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), §6.10.1 (Conditional inclusion):

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers are replaced with the pp-number 0

In other words, in an #if or #elif directive, any macros that cannot be expanded, because they don't exist/are undefined, will behave exactly as if they'd been defined as 0, and therefore will always be equal to each other.

You can catch likely unintended behavior like this in GCC/clang with the warning option [-Wundef](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) (you'll probably want to make it fatal with -Werror=undef).

Answer (score 11):

The preprocessor runs before the compiler, which means that the preprocessor doesn't know anything about symbols defined by the compiler and therefore it can't act depending on them.

Comment: Please see reasoning above.

Comment: @Gnubie you don't need to use the preprocessor `#if` for this. See my edit to my answer above.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers explain why what you're trying doesn't work; for an alternative, I'd probably go with:

```
#define RGB 1
#define GREY 2
#define CMYK 3
#define MODE RGB

#if MODE == RGB
    //RGB-mode code
#elif MODE == GREY
    //Greyscale code
#elif MODE == CMYK
    //CMYK code
#else
#    error Undefined MODE
#endif
```

You might want prefixes on the RGB/GREY/CMYK if there's a danger of clashes with "real" source code.

Comment: That was my first thought, then I thought I could be clever and use an enum, and then wondered why it didn't work...

Comment: @Gnubie Learn to ignore or at least seriously distrust the little voices that say "this could be done cleverly using <x>"....they'll usually lead you astray. "Clever" is not often "good".

Answer (score 3):

The posts have explained why, but a possible solution for you that keeps readability might be like this

```
#define MODE_RGB

int main()
{        
    #ifdef MODE_RGB
        std::cout << "RGB mode" << std::endl;
    #elif defined MODE_GREY
        std::cout << "Grey mode" << std::endl;
    #elif defined MODE_CMYK
        std::cout << "CMYK mode" << std::endl;
    #endif
}
```

You just then need to change the macro at the top, to only the macro you are interested in is defined. You could also include a check to make sure that one and only one is defined and if not then and do `#error "You must define MODE_RGB, MODE_GREY or MODE_CMYK`

Comment: Great idea! I think I'll use this technique.