# using enum values in preprocessor directive

Tags: c, preprocessor

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {A, B};

#define C A

int main() {
#if C == B
  printf("%d==%d\n", C, B);
#else
  printf("%d!=%d\n", C, B);
#endif
}
```

which, surprinsingly, gives the output:

```
0==1
```

Now, I understand that the code is wrong, because enum values are unknown to the preprocessor. What I don't understand is why no error is generated... A and B should be undefined at preprocessing time, how is that the preprocessor gives no error?

Comment: See anser for your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677148/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-consider-enum-values-as-equal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the C preprocessor consider enum values as equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677148/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-consider-enum-values-as-equal)

Answer (score 9):

The preprocessor runs in a separate phase before the compiler proper handles the source. As such it doesn't know anything about symbols in the actual source code (like enumerations or variables).

For the preprocessor the symbol `B` is an unknown macro and when used in that context (`#if C == B`) it will be equal to zero. Since the symbol `A` is *also* not a macro, it will also evaluate to zero. All this lease to the comparison `#if 0 == 0` which is indeed true.

See e.g. [this phases of translation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) for more information about translation phases, and [this preprocessor conditional reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional) for more information about that.

Comment: Equal to zero, or be an empty token sequence?

Comment: @StoryTeller I've read somewhere that in such a context it's equal to zero. I'll try to dig something up.

Comment: Empty token sequence in #if comparision is equal to zero

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Now I read it too :) https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4

Comment: @StoryTeller From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional): "Any identifier, which is not literal, non defined using `#define` directive, evaluates to 0."