# why does the preprocessor identifies the enum values with Borland C++ but not with visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, c-preprocessor, borland-c++

I am trying to migrate a project from `Borland C++` to `Visual C++`

I noticed a difference in treating enum as explained by this example

File : Test_enum.cpp

```
    #ifdef  _MSC_VER
        #include <iostream>
    #else
        #include <iostream.h>
    #endif
    #include <conio.h>

    using namespace std;

    enum {

        ENUM_0 =0,
        ENUM_1,
        ENUM_2,
        ENUM_3
        } ;

     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        #ifdef  _MSC_VER
        cout << "Microsoft Visual compiler detected!" << endl;
        #elif defined(__BORLANDC__)
        cout << "Borland compiler detected!" << endl;
        #elif
        cout << "Other compiler detected!" << endl;
        #endif
        #if ENUM_1 > 0
        cout << "ENUM_1 is well defined at preprocessing time" << endl;
        #else
        cout << "No way to see enum variables at preprocessing time" << endl;
        #endif
        cout << "Type any character to exit..." << endl;

        #ifdef  _MSC_VER
            _getch();
        #else
            getch();
        #endif

        return 0;
    }
```

Runing the code in visual studio gives this output :

```
Microsoft Visual compiler detected!
No way to see enum variables at preprocessing time
Type any character to exit...
```

And by using Borland, i get :

```
Borland Compiler detected!
ENUM_1 is well defined at preprocessing time
Type any character to exit...
```

I want to know how `Borland` is able to recognize the `enum` ? Is it possible to do the same in `visual` ?

Comment: the preprocessor knows nothing about enums or their value. Sloppy speaking the preprocessor is only about textual replacement

Comment: `Enum` should be `enum` btw and you have a trailing `,`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: trailing comma is valid. I suspect case issue is due to auto capitalization of some application (before copy/pasting).

Comment: Do you have a line with `#define b <some_value>` somewhere? If you change the `#if` line to `#if jkshdfghfg > 0`, do you still get `true`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe your Borland C++ compiler defines `b`? What happens if you cout << b?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No it doesn't define it. And yes i get true when replacing  'b' with 'jkshdfghfg > 0'.

Comment: @M.M i can't post the code due to the project's privacy.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am actually migrating code from Borland C++ to Visual C++. And what i noticed that Borland can compile '#if b>0' but for visual, 'b' is ==0.

Comment: do you want to understand the output you get as you ask in the title or do you want to know how to conditionally `cout` something based on the underlying value of `a`? For the first i'd try to see what `#ifdef a` does, for the latter you dont need to use macros

Comment: Make a MRE that gives the same problem. Surely you can do this without using the exact code of the private project

Comment: or try `cout << b;` as suggested before

Comment: or maybe you have a `#define b 123` somewhere hidden in your code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 `cout<< b` gives 2.
When i use `#define b 2`, the condition is verified.

Comment: If I try your code I get `false`.

Comment: I'm inspired from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677148/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-consider-enum-values-as-equal).

Comment: @TedLyngmo that can't make sense, because the preprocessor treats only macros and directives, as a result the value of `b` is `0` !!! And here is my problem, Borland seems to recognize the enum values, But Visual C++ dosen't.

Comment: did you also read the answers? They already explain why your code is not doing what you expect. To be honest now I wonder why you expected this to work and I am tempted to flag it as a duplcate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677148/why-does-the-c-preprocessor-consider-enum-values-as-equal

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes i did. In fact my problem is the opposite of his, i expect that my `a`, `b` and `c` values are `0` in the `#if ` because they can't be seen by the preprocessor( As the answers said) and that's how it works in `Visual C++`. However, in `Borland C++` `a` , `b` and `c` have the values `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: frankly speaking, the problem is that you expect anything from this macros. What problem are you actually trying to solve? If you want to `cout` something depending on the value of `a` then simply do not use macros!

Comment: It does **not** care for the `b` defined in the `enum`. In fact, I can remove the complete `enum` and it will still compile and it still prints `false`, like expected.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am trying to figure how `Borland c++` is doing so, in order to be able to applied in`Visual C++`
I thought of transforming the enums values to directives `#define` but that seems "impossible" due to the huge number of enum values (over 10000).

Comment: I use Borland C++ Builder myself and I get `false` so this is not a Borland thing.

Comment: "I thought of transforming the enums values to directives #define" why? this seems like making a big step into the past. I dont see any advantage of doing that and uncountable problems to be encountered. What is your motivation behind that?

Comment: Yes,  Borland (or Embarcadero) C++ Builder 10.3.1.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well this is insane !! 
@formerlyknownas_463035818 because that's the only way that a `#if` will be able to recognize the values of `a`, `b` and `c` and so `#if b>0` is verified.

Comment: why do you insist on `#if b>0` ?? Why do you want to use macros so much? I dont see any reason for using macros. Macros come with lots of problems that can be avoided by simply not using them

Comment: What happens if you remove the `enum` completely and just do `std::cout << b;`? Does it compile? If so, what value is printed? If you really want to use the `enum`s for activating different parts of your code, use `if constexpr (b>0) {...} else {...}`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 as Ted said, the purpose of using macros and the `enum` is to activate parts of code.
@TedLyngmo the code compiles, the value is `false`.
Can `constexpr` assure the same functionality ?

Comment: "the purpose of using macros and the enum is to activate parts of code." I dont think this is what Ted is trying to say. He wrote " If you really want to use the enums for activating different parts of your code, use if constexpr (b>0) {...} else {...}"  ie no macros needed. Dont get me wrong, but your "problem" is a bit like "doctor, when I hit my leg with a hammer, it hurts, what should I do?" ... understanding the difference you observe is interesting from an academical point of view, but to activate parts of your code you do not need macros! They were needed in past decades but not anymore

Comment: Please show your complete program. It shouldn't compile. The functionality is like a regular if but requires a compiletime constant expression.

Comment: Please post a **minimal complete C++ program** that prints one thing in BC++ and another thing in VC++. What you have posted is a program fragment taken out of an unknown context. Try it in a freshly created project, not in your existing project.

Comment: For an added bonus, post the exact command lines BC++ runs to compile and link your program.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 • "Doctor, I stopped hitting my leg with a hammer.  But your advice did not work.  Now I'm hitting it with a baseball bat, and it still hurts!"

Comment: I edited the post as you recommended @M.M

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 what do you think ?

Comment: I think you turned the question into a nice one. I dont know an online compiler that lets you compile with borland, but in general it is better to provide live examples that others can reproduce rather than images of the output. Also for the first time your motivation is clear. However, if you want to migrate this code to proper C++ you should get rid of the macros alltogether, the only reason I am not writing this as answer is that imho a complete answer should also explain why it works with borland (actually what you get with vs is the expected output)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 thank you, I hope that someone can explain why it works with Borland.

Comment: `<iostream.h>` ??? What version of the compiler was used in the Borland project? Must be an extremely old one.

Comment: Any compiler that needs `#include <iostream.h>` is hopelessly outdated and any code written for it needs to be rewritten. It doesn't matter how it does what it does, it's simply irrelevant. Rewrite it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  Not sure of the version but it dates to the 90s xD

Answer (score 7):

The old, obsolete and totally irrelevant Borland C++ compiler had some unique quirks. One of them is that you can use C++ constant expressions in preprocessor directives.

```
#if sizeof -1 > 0
    cout << "It looks like you got lucky today" << endl;
#endif

const int answer = 42;
#if answer == 42
    cout << "Unbelievable" << endl;
#endif
```

There is absolutely no chance in hell you can get any of this to work with any modern compiler.

Comment: @Quentin you can download BC++ and test it for yourself. I did.

Comment: No need, we actually have to use it at work... Hadn't encountered that maleficent feature yet, though.

Answer (score 4):

A preprocessor directive `#IF` is only necessary if something can only be conditionally parsed, e.g. if one file has

```
#define SPECIAL_FLAG 1
void only_available_if_special_flag_set();
```

then you might want, in another file

```
#IF SPECIAL_FLAG_SET
    only_available_if_special_flag_set();
#ENDIF
```

Of course, the big disadvantage of `#IF` is that it can only read other preprocessor-related values.  While Borland's very special `#IF` can read compile-time constant values, the real-deal `#IF` cannot.

---

C++17's `if constexpr` will handle the case where both alternatives can be parsed, but compilation is conditional.  For instance

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::string, decltype(foo)>) {
  return foo;
} else {
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << foo;
  return out.str();
}
```

---

But I have a hunch that all you *really* need is a regular old `if` statement.  Compilers have been able to conditionally compile `if` statements with compile-time-constant predicates for a while now, and so from a performance perspective, a regular `if` is the same as the very special Borland `#IF` or C++17's `if constexpr`.  For instance,

```
if (int(ENUM_1) > 0) {
  algorithm_which_depends_on_positive_enum_1();
} else {
  fallback_algorithm_for_negative_enum_1();
}
```

Comment: A regular `IF` doesn't play the same role as `#IF`, the two parts of the condition are evaluated by the compiler.

Comment: @AchrafBelkahla  No, they don't play *all* of the same roles all of the time.  But in the code in your question, both branches of the `#IF` are grammatical and typecheck (the requirements for regular `if`), and the predicate is a compile-time constant (such that that the compiler can ignore one branch and emit binary only for the other).  So in _this_ context, `if` does play the same role as special-Borland-`#IF` or of `if constexpr`.